# Cant click a button using Selenium webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have been trying out Selenium WebDriver using Java. I can easily get some clicks done on buttons with an ID, selecting from dropdownboxes by value and even typing on input fields.

I'm trying to make and automation to browse through different categories on a reports platform and get certain reports downloaded by filling the date_start and date_end. Went well using:

```
WebElement startDate = driver.findElement(By.id("start_date"));
startDate.sendKeys("25082021");
WebElement endDate = driver.findElement(By.id("end_date"));
endDate.sendKeys("25092021");
```

The problem is to finally click a download button 'ExcelHtml5' that is part of Datatables.

[Javascript inside of PHP:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqOJZ.png)

[Inspect code of the Excel button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFqWC.png)

I have tried getting the click done using By.xpath() and By.cssSelector()

But no luck.. here are the latest rows of code I have tried:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement edit_button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#dt-button.buttons-excel.buttons-html5.btn.btn-success.btn-sm.downloadExcel\"")));
edit_button.click();
```

and another approach:

```
WebElement excelButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='downloadExcel'][@type='button'][contains(text(),'Excel')]"));
excelButton.click();
```

In less than half an hour I got everything ready except the click of 'Excel'-download button. I've tried hard looking for answers on the web and finally after using about 6 hours on getting this Excel button to be clicked using Selenium WebDriver but with no success. I have tried chrome extensions like XPath Helper and Chropath to get the cssSelector.

Anyone who could help me please?

Update:
Problem was caused of a new tab that was opened during the process. After using @cruisepandey code solution I got the reports to download successfully!

Corrected code was:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs =  new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` if we have unique entry in HTML DOM or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> `go to element section` -> `do a CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired element is getting highlighted.

**Update 1 (Java):**

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//span[text()='Excel']/parent::button[@aria-controls='report'][contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Excel']/parent::button[@aria-controls='report'][contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]")).click();
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Excel']/parent::button[@aria-controls='report'][contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]"))).click();
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Excel']/parent::button[@aria-controls='report'][contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Excel']/parent::button[@aria-controls='report'][contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

**Update 2 :**

```
ArrayList<String> tabs =  new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Comment: Your provided xpath  //div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')] highlights the Excel button nicely. I tried code trial 1 and 2, but it justs sits there and shows a click animation but it doesn't really click the button. I'll go through trials 3-4 and let you know asap! :)

Comment: I think it may need JS intervention, Please try with 3rd one.

Comment: Okay so I had to do some tweaking with the trial codes to get tests done.
Here is the codes I tested: https://ibb.co/MB43qPy
The trial 4 code did not move the mouse :/ Seems quite weird that the xpath seems correct but still doesn't click on it.

Comment: Here is a dpaste of the code used: https://dpaste.com/7TLHQNPC6

Comment: Here is the example for adding ExcelHtml5 export button using Datatables:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html
And the changes for the Excel button:
dom: 'Bfrtlp',
                    buttons: [
                        {extend: 'excelHtml5', className: 'btn btn-success btn-sm downloadExcel', title:''}
                    ],

It should produce html as:
<button class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn btn-success btn-sm downloadExcel" tabindex="0" aria-controls="report" type="button"><span>Excel</span></button>

Comment: Just incase you want to try replicating the datatable with the Excel export button, I might be able to create an seperate window for testing, but I'm afraid I need to quit for the today. Been 1,5hours overtime at work :P

Comment: You are using this `driver.findElement(By.id("//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]")).click();` which should have been `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]")).click();` do test this only, and share the error stack trace if it occurs.

Comment: Tried it and got this error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='dt-buttons']//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]"}

Comment: Are you sure that it is not in any iframe ? Where is the element located in UI ? can you share the entire page resource here with a shareable link ?

Comment: Here is the page source: https://dpaste.com/CP3R9V9K6 
Doesn't seem to be in a iframe
<button class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn btn-success btn-sm downloadExcel" tabindex="0" aria-controls="report" type="button"><span>Excel</span></button> is inside of <div id="report_wrapper" and <div class="dt-buttons. Maybe the xpath needs to know about all the divs inside body/main?

Comment: iframe does not have to parent, it could be ancestor, please write this `//iframe` in dev tools just like you searched for xpath yesterday and see how many entries are there ? also try with `//frame` and `//frameset`

Comment: All 3 searches did not find a match on source

Comment: then we are sure that we do not have to deal with iframe, I'm working on this ticket, will let you know shortly. meanwhile I have construct a xpath `//span[text()='Excel']/parent::button[@aria-controls='report'][contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]` please try, I will also give you solution in Java in few mins

Comment: @Manny :  See above Update1 code in Java. I hope this will work for you now. Yesterday we had missed `build` while we were trying actions class

Comment: I just realized something that could be the reason but I'm not sure cause I have really little knowledge of Selenium. The whole proccess is this atm: Enter autologin webpage, enter report page using driver.get(url) on both, set start and end dates, selection from two dropdownboxes, click on create report that opens a new tab whrere I need to click an Excel button. Could it be that this new tab is the problem?

Comment: oh man is it a new windows  ?or new tab ? if yes then we have to switch. I was actually thinking it could be the issue, but since you've not mentioned I ignored it.

Comment: I had no idea it could be a problem, but just now realized that "create report"-button opens a new tab.  Deeply sorry for not bringing this up yesterday

Comment: @Manny :  Not an issue, we learn everyday. See the above update 2 section where I have given you the code to switch to new windows, also you should write this after once you click the create report link.

Comment: So the problem was that the new tab was not selected and by using above solution corrected the problem. I'm really happy that this got resolved even I had not given all the information needed. Thank you @cruisepandey for helping me! The report got downloaded and now I just need to close the current tab, select a new report, create report, move to the second tab again and click download :P

Comment: @Manny :  had that info little early, would have solved the issue yesterday itself. But glad we could work together to close this ticket. Have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement edit_button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]")));
edit_button.click();
```

In case `//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')]` XPath is not unique locator try this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement edit_button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel') and(contains(@class,'btn-success'))]")));
edit_button.click();
```

Comment: First try:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel')] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)


The second code gave me this error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //button[contains(@class,'downloadExcel') and(contains(@class,'btn-success'))] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: I wish I could but its an company inside platform :/